# How to get any id(value) from object as per value selection in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, filter

I have an object having key value pair i.e. id and value as attached below.

```
var dataObject = [
    {
        "value": "A",
        "id": 1,
    },
    {
        "value": "B",
        "id": 2,
    },
    {
        "value": "C",
        "id": 3,
    },
    {
        "value": "D",
        "id": 4,
    },
    {
        "value": "E",
        "id": 5,
    }
]
```

I am selecting value from multiselector from front end, for example I am selecting B and C

```
var selectedData = ['B', 'C']
```

I am expecting below object to send as a payload from dataObject.

```
"selection": [
    {
      "siteId": 2
    },
    {
      "siteId": 3
    }
  ],
```

I have tried with ***filter()*** and ***map()*** like this

```
var result = dataObject.filter(item => item.value === 'B').map(item => item.id);
```

But not get proper result

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `includes` Array method.

```js
var result = dataObject.filter(item => selectedData.includes(item.value) ).map(item => ({siteId:item.id}));
```

BTW, It will only work if the order of selectedData is the same as dataObject.

Comment: Thanks Hao-Jung it's really works to me.